# Is this an error in "More Effective C++" in Item28?

Tags: c++

I encountered a question when I was reading the item28 in *More Effective C++*.  In this item, the author shows to us that we can use member template in `SmartPtr` such that the `SmartPtr<Cassette>` can be converted to `SmartPtr<MusicProduct>`.
The following code is not the same as in the book, but has the same effect.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};

template<typename T>
class smart {
public:
    smart(T* ptr)
        : ptr(ptr)
    {}

    template<typename U>
    operator smart<U>()
    {
        return smart<U>(ptr);
    }

    ~smart()
    {
        delete ptr;
    }
private:
    T* ptr;
};

void test(const smart<Base>& ) {}

int main()
{
    smart<Derived> sd(new Derived);
    test(sd);
    return 0;
}
```

It indeed can be compiled without compilation error. But when I ran the executable file, I got a core dump. I think that's because the member function of the conversion operator makes a temporary smart, which has a pointer to the same ptr in `sd` (its type is `smart<Derived>`). So the delete directive operates twice. What's more, after calling test, we can never use `sd` any more, since `ptr` in `sd` has already been delete.
Now my questions are :

- Is my thought right? Or my code is not the same as the original code in the book?
- If my thought is right, is there any method to do this?

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Your code is not the same as the original code in the book. The intent of code in the book is to show how smart pointers, even though they're templated, can work around `Base` and `Derived` being different types, albeit in the same class hierarchy. Your implementation demonstrates that type conversion mechanism, but differs from smart pointer in not having a reference count check before calling `delete` This brings it closer to what smart ptr is doing: `~smart() {if (reference_count_ < 1) delete ptr;}`. Typically, some mutex may protect counter between refcount check and `delete`.

Comment: Oh, I get your point. The original code didn't show the implementation of the constructor and destructor. I incorrectly used the `std::auto_ptr`'s ctor and dtor in the test code, which has no reference counting and thus is not suitable in this case. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you've described the problem with your code fairly accurately.

As far as how to make it work: just about like the usual when you run into problems from a shallow copy: do a deep copy instead. That is, instead of just creating another pointer to the same data, you'd need to clone the data, and have the second object point to the clone of the data instead of the original data.

Alternatively, use a reference counted pointer, and increment the reference count when you do a copy, and decrement it when a copy is destroyed. When the count reaches zero (and not before) delete the pointee data.

Generally speaking: avoid doing all of this. Assuming you're using a relatively up-to-date compiler, the standard library should already contain a `shared_ptr` and a `unique_ptr` that can handle a *lot* of your smart pointer needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I use `shared_ptr`, can it avoid destroying the raw pointer after passing `shared_ptr<Derived>` to `test(const shared_ptr<Base>&)`? If so, how does it handle the problem?

Comment: @particle128: `shared_ptr` uses reference counting, about as described just before in the answer. I don't remember if it provides this conversion though--I'd have to check to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your interpretation is correct, the conversion operator will create a different object that holds a pointer to the same underlying object. Once it goes out of scope it will be destroyed, and it will in turn call `delete`.

Not sure I understand the last question, if what you ask is whether this can be useful or not, it can be useful if implemented correctly. For example, if instead of a raw pointer and manually allocating/deleting the memory you were using a `std::shared_ptr` then it would work just fine. In other cases there might not even be a dynamically allocated object... This is just a tool, use it where it makes sense.